# Yii 2 Exclude NavBar in Modal

Tags: php, modal-dialog, yii2

In my `index.php` view, I have a button, once clicked, a modal will pop up:

```
<p>
    <?= Html::button(
        'Create New BizAdmin',
        ['value' => Url::to(['createbizadmin']),
        'class' => 'btn btn-success',
            'id' => 'modalButton'

        ]) ?>


    <?php
        Modal::begin(['id' => 'modal']);
            echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";     
        Modal::end();
    ?>
</p>
```

My modal file is `createbizadmin.php` where it has the following codes:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;


/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\User */

$this->title = 'Create New Bizadmin';
?>
<div class="user-create">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= $this->render('_formbizadmin', [
        'model1' => $model1,
        'model2' => $model2,
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

My problem is this:
[image]

As you can see, the navbar looks horrible. The menu list seems to overflow outside the modal.

**How do I get rid of the navbar inside my modal?** I can't seem to find which part of `creatbizadmin.php` I should edit.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have a controller somewhere that is handling the url `createbizadmin`. I'm also guessing that inside that controller action you are rendering the view file like this;

```
$this->render("createbizadmin");
```

If so, then that is your problem. By calling a view file directly, Yii will apply default layouts to the view file. You have no control over how this happens from within the called view file, and all your menus etc will be rendered.

To get around this you will probably need to render a partial file. This rendres the file without applying layouts. So use;

```
$this->renderPartial("createbizadmin")
```

Alternatively, if the modal content is being generated as a result of an ajax call, you can respond from the controller with;

```
$this->renderAjax("createbizadmin")
```

This article seems to have a good explanation of how best to achieve this; [Render a form in a modal popup](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/690/render-a-form-in-a-modal-popup-using-ajax/)